# PMDC motor calculations spreadsheet

Tags: dc-motor

I've been trying to design a spreadsheet for the design of a DC motor for a class project. We are expected to design everything from scratch which means choosing our wire type, number of coils, permanent magnets etc.

However we are completely stuck and our spreadsheet is providing more questions than answers. The teaching staff are not able to provide any help with it so I'm wondering if anyone knows where we have gone wrong with our calculations. At the end of it all we are trying to work out the motor efficiency given certain wire types, permanent magnets, number of conductors, build dimensions etc.

I've searched for other Excel docs but all I can find are ones where all of our variables such as no load and full load speed are already known. None seem to offer calculations for design.

[Excel file] *(link removed)*

Would anyone be able to have a look through and offer any advice please?

Comment: Do you think many people will open an excel file given it can contain naughty and nasty things?

Comment: This question is problematic on many levels. First of all, Excel is a proprietary file format that can contain executable code (macros) that can be malicious. You'll have to find another way to express yourself here. (We have a fine math typsetting tool built into this site.) Secondly, as posed this question is far too broad -- you need to narrow it down to the specfic equations you're having trouble with or issues you're running into.

Answer (score 2):

This is too big of a problem for me to comment on everything in your spreadsheet.  When you are taking an analytic approach like this to motor design the general procedure is to:

Model your armature, air gap, magnet, etc as a magnetic circuit.  This can get quite complicated.  You will generally break down your magnetic circuit into different materials (steel, magnet, air, etc.) and then break those down even further based on flux density.  The goal is to solve the magnetic circuit for B, H, reluctance, flux, MMF's, etc.  This step generally has to be done either graphically or iteratively because of the nonlinearity of BH curves.

From this you'll get air gap flux (per pole) and you can use that along with the effective number of conductors, the number of poles, etc. to find your torque/back-emf constant.  From that you can determine developed torque for any current.  You'll need to have a basic model of your brushes and commutator and also you'll need determine your losses (I^2*R losses, core losses, friction, etc.).  Depending how complicated you want to make things you can use the losses to estimate the temperature rise of your components and then go back and redo all your calculations since all your materials properties will be dependent on temperature.  Or you can just assume a temperature at the beginning of your calculations.

I can comment briefly on your spreadsheet.

- You don't currently have anything in there modeling the material or shape of your lamination.  The MMF drop in your lamination and steel housing will be big enough relative to your air gap MMF that you won't want to ignore it.
- You are using \$B_r\$ as your magnet flux density but that is not the flux density that your magnet will operate at.  Look into a term called the "permeance coefficient."  It is based on the geometry of your magnet and air gap.  It will basically tell you where your magnet is operating on the magnet's BH curve.  You'll need to know \$H_c\$ for your magnet as well.
- It is okay to assume a flux leakage like you are doing but 50% is waaaaay too high, unless your motor is really poorly designed.  It will probably be more in the neighborhood of 5-15%, depending on your design.
- Your calculation for output power is taking full load torque times no load speed.  You can't do that.  Your speed will be slower at full load than at no load.
- Personally I wouldn't use a spreadsheet for this.  It can be done but you would be better off using something like Matlab or, even better, Python.  The one nice thing about a spreadsheet is you will have hundreds of variables you need to keep track of (again, depending how accurately you want to model and how many assumptions you make).  If you insist on a spreadsheet, I would suggest using VBA to do some of the iterative calculations you'll need to do.

Comment: Awesome thank you for this. I feel like we haven't actually been shown how to do most of these things, and to model a motor with all these considerations is a little too ambitious for the introductory course we are taking. I might have a chat to the lecturer and bring this up. Thanks again